# Copying view model to data model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to develop my first ASP.net MVC project with Entity Framework. I wasn't using any view models, i was using same models for both in views and database transactions. Here is the thing, i have custom user table. In creation, i have 5 things in my `User` model: `UserName`, `UserPassword`, `FullName`, `Branch` and `BranchId`(Navigation to another table). But when i want to edit a user, i don't need the UserPassword field, because changing the password won't be possible for now. So i created a model same with the `User` model except the `UserPassword` field named `UserEdit`.

In create view i use my User model, in edit view i use the UserEdit model. In controller i'm using automapper and copy values from `User` to `UserEdit` and return that to view. It's working fine, problem is about updating.

I'm trying to update the user like this:

```
    public bool Update(UserEdit userEdit) {
        User user = Find(userEdit.UserUsername);

        Mapper.CreateMap<UserEdit, User>();

        user = (User)Mapper.Map(userEdit, user, typeof(UserEdit), typeof(User));

        if (_modelState.IsValid)
        {
            _transactionManager.GetContext().Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            _transactionManager.CommitTransaction();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But it gives me this error:

> Additional information: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

When i check the user i'm trying to update, i see Entity Framework related objects in it. So i'm thinking reason of this error is probably about branch table and those related objects in the user object. I really don't need those entity related objects in my user object. If i could only copy the properties in the model, it would be great. Maybe i'm doing something else wrong. Because i know people use view models all the time, there should be an easy way to do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing your models (data and view model), but check that all the properties are being updated.

Comment: I actually said how my models are, there are only 5 fields on my main model, view model is the same, only missing password field.

Comment: Show them, and the view (and it would make no sense to have `Branch` and `BranchID` in a view model)

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be rolling your own password authentication. Use what's built into MVC. That said, the easiest way to save your view model would be this;

```
using (YourContext db = new YourContext())
{
  User u = db.User.Find(userEdit.UserUsername);
  db.Entity(u).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
  u.FullName = userEdit.FullName;
  ....set the other properties here...

  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I can do that but i thought it would be better to do it with automapper.

Comment: Automapper introduces an extra level of complexity. It has its place, but for mapping 5 fields, I would not use it. For your first project, keep it simple take advantage of automapper when you have a better understanding of models.